# Navigationbar not repositioning after adding statusbar

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a navigationbar-positioning problem that seems to have appeared with iOS6.
It acts in many ways similar to the proplem some users are experiencing when rotating some views

The app has a splash screen, displayed full screen (achieved by setting `Hide statusbar during application launch` to `True`)

Then in `viewDidLoad` in my Master View Controller the following line adds the statusbar back to the app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

This adds the StatusBar to the app, and shifts the view downwards 20pt as expected.
However, the NavigationBar stays put, underneath the StatusBar with a 20pt glitch underneath.

[image: The glitch created by adding statusBar]

Before iOS6 I used to fix this by adding the following line of code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-20);
```

Now, however, this do not work.

Some research shows that at the time of calling `viewDidLoad`, `keyWindow.frame` has a size and origin both of {0,0}, and altering it has no effect.

When inserting the two lines mentioned above to `viewDidAppear` I get the same behaviour when the app launches. When I dhen move to another view and back to the first view however, the alteration of `keyWindow.frame` has the desired effect and the NavigationBar ends up positioned where it should be.

My question then: How to make the NavigationBar gets it's right position after adding the StatusBar to an iOS-app when the StatusBar is initially hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I'm asleap at work again:

The effect of doing things in the other methods (`view[Will|Did]Appear`) do not apply since the statusbar are already displayed by the calling from `viewDidLoad`. I did remove the code from there and then got the desired effect from `viewDidAppear`. Any of the methods called earlier do not alter the child frame. (Neither `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` alters the frame of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame`)

So this has to be done in `viewDidAppear`. Just make sure the statusbar has not aleready been displayed in some of the methods called before...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call setStatusBarHidden:NO on viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: Tried. Samme effect on all the view[Will|Did][Appear|Load] methods.

Comment: Weird, I had the exact same problem and  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide] worked, but only from viewWillAppear

Comment: You know; this is me being silly/tired again. Since the `setStatusBarHidden:NO` were still in the `wiewDidLoad` method, the subsequent calls did behave different. The only place I got things working were in `viewDidAppear` and only with both the calls (as the frame of the view did not adjust when adding statusBar in any of the calls, and only were responsive in the last one to be fired (`viewDidAppear`).

Comment: Aha that explains it, good that you got it working! :) Now I'm even more interested in why my solution only works on viewWillAppear..

Comment: This have been giving me headaches as well. Problem (as many others) first surfaced with iOS6.

Comment: Btw, when I put it in `viewWillApear` the statusBar showed up, but neither the navBar nor the view shifted...